# Tyre Pressure & Wheel Alignment

Tags: tires, alignment

Long story short, got front end wheel alignment done but it was quite off centre, checked my tyre pressure and there was a 3-4 PSI difference between each tyre.

Am I correct to assume tyre pressure needs to be the same across the axle for an accurate alignment otherwise it will always be off? Or is it just a bad alignment job in general?

Comment: How have you determined that the alignment is off-center?

Comment: The alignment is done from the wheels rims, not from the tyres. But I would bet money that no two wheel shops will give the same readings.

Comment: If you take it back to the shop it might be worth asking them to check for damage to the suspension. I once had this issue where the shop would align the wheels whilst the car was on the lift in the air, but they would become unaligned when on the ground. There was a crack in a shock tower that caused the car to flex slightly when there was weight on the wheels.

Comment: @GdD With steering on center the car drifts slightly left. If I turn the wheel slightly to the right it is centered with wheels and drives straight.

Comment: @MeltingDog Went to another shop to get an alignment and they checked my suspension parts and said bushings on suspension arms/wishbones are basically gone, so advised to get that changed and another alignment at this stage was useless. This may have been the culprit?

Comment: @Dave1UK yeah I think if the bushings were gone there would be a lot of movement. I'd say that would be a good candidate for the problem